# Failure to find org.spockframework:spock-core:jar:1.0-groovy-2.3-SNAPSHOT in Spock Example project

Tags: groovy, maven-3, spock, gmaven

Trying to use Spock via GMaven (Maven 3.1.1) with Groovy 2.3 support and I am having difficulty getting SNAPSHOT dependency.  I seem to have same error even when I try to run Spock Example project that has similar dependency defined.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-groovy-2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have the SNAPSHOT repository specified like the Spock Example does:

```
<repositories>
    <!-- Only required if a snapshot version of Spock is used -->
    <repository>
        <id>spock-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

But even when I run `mvn clean test` for [Spock Example](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example) I get:

ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project spock-example: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.spockframework:spock-example:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.spockframework:spock-core:jar:1.0-groovy-2.3-SNAPSHOT in  was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus_sprn has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

I succeed if I simply use 0.7-groovy-2.0 version but I want Groovy 2.3 since it appears @CompileStatic does not work properly for my project in Groovy 2.0.

EDIT:

Just notice a warning happening just before the build fails:

[WARNING] The POM for org.spockframework:spock-core:jar:1.0-groovy-2.3-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

Comment: have you tried `mvn clean -U` ?

Comment: Trying that now...I have blown away my .m2/repository directory if that is similar.

Comment: this forces an update on snapshots... the error looked like it's not in local and it refuses to try again.  worth a shot...

Comment: Thanks, not a Maven guru.  More comfortable with Gradle or Grails build but it's been a year since I've been on the JVM also.

Comment: Looks like you have a Maven proxy configured which doesn't know about the Spock snapshot repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on Mr. Niederwiesser's comment I found that the settings.xml my current project requires uses a mirror that does not know about the Spock SNAPSHOT location.  In addition to re-configuring my company's proxy setting I had to do the following in my global `settings.xml` to make it not use the mirror.

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>nexus_sprn</id>
        <mirrorOf>*,!nexus_public,!project-lib-dir,!spock-snapshots</mirrorOf>
        <url>MIRROR_URL_REMOVED</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

...

```
<repository>
    <id>spock-snapshots</id>
    <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

Not sure proper etiquette here but I will leave this answer here for future unless the general consensus is it is unnecessary.